# segmentation violation Segmentation fault c++ with values in numerator array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to calculate a ratio and it works when my numerator array is full with 0, but when I have values in the numerator array breaks the program.

```
223 Double_t *ratio_calculations(int bin_numbers, Double_t *flux_data)
224 {
225         Double_t *ratio;
226         for(int n = 0; n <bin_numbers; n++)
227         {
228                 if(0 < flux_data[n])
229                 {
230
231                         ratio[n] = ygraph.axis_array[n]/flux_data[n];
232                 }
233         }
234         return ratio;
235 }
```

I have no idea why it happens, and yes I have checked the lengths of my arrays and they are the same as the value of bin_numbers.

Comment: You forget to allocate the memory to ratio.

Comment: @user1438832 you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need determine the correct size for `ratio`, allocate the memory, and finally, make sure you fill `ratio`
correctly as you filter invalid data with the `if` statement:

```
Double_t *ratio_calculations(int bin_numbers, Double_t *flux_data) {
  // get correct size
  int sz = 0;
  for (int n = 0; n < bin_numbers; n++) {
    if (flux_data[n] > 0) sz++;
  }
  Double_t *ratio = new Double_t[sz];
  // allocate with non-n index, as n increments even when data is invalid (flux_data[n] < 0)
  int r_idx = 0
  for (int n = 0; n <bin_numbers; n++) {
    if (flux_data[n] > 0) {
      ratio[r_idx] = ygraph.axis_array[n]/flux_data[n];
      r_idx++;
    }
  }
  return ratio;
}
```

Comment: Remember to delete ratio when you do not need it anymore! Or better use vector instead.

Comment: @Logman. I hope the OP knows this ;). OP, `delete [] ratio;` when you're done.